# In ajax i want compare json object and string

Tags: ajax

```
// this is ajax response in json obj it print 'policyListing'
alert(response.result[i].screenName);

alert(response.result[i].screenName=='policyListing');// it return false
```

It should return true. I do not know where is the problem how to get true

Comment: It probably doesn't print `'policyListing'`, more likely it prints `'policyListing '` or some other subtle variation.

Comment: I recomemnd you to do: `alert(typeof response.result[i].screenName);` to be sure you have a string here

Answer (score 0):

The variable-type of screenName could be an object. You can check the type of a variable with `alert( typeof(response.result[i].screenName) );`
If the var is not a string-type, you can try to convert it into a string with .toString().
Example:

```
alert(response.result[i].screenName.toSting() == 'policyListing');
```

Comment: While this code-only answer may answer the question, it is usually better to give an explaination in addition to the code.